# Are well formed "if, then" statements non-contigent truths?

Tags: truth, falsifiability, contingent

Say I have a little unease with statements like "the world follows/obeys the law of non-contradiction, so x". But statements like "if the world obeys the lnc, then x", appear so secure I don't know what could undermine them. Some if/then statements are so secure, even if math were fictional they hold. Not all "if, then" statements are like this - "if a hippo is blue, then it likes cucumbers" could be defeated. I'm only asking about the class of if/then statements which seem impossible to undermine: if F=2*m*a, then ___, if the universe had 39 spatial dimensions and 2 time, then __, if 2(3)=6, then 3(2)=6, or if modus ponens is used, then __ is valid.

You could say "hey, 2(3)=6 doesn't imply 3(2)=6 in some systems, aha!". So really I'm leaving out a lot of detail, but adding in a finite amount of proper detail would secure these statements or similar against all routing (I claim). Or at least, the if/then version of any statement is stronger against subversion than their normal counterparts (e.g. the lnc example).

This isn't about pragmatics or semantics - I'm not worried if in science we really mean, "if the theory is true, then x" instead of "the model predicts x". I'm wondering about this class of objects/statements which seem more secure than any other type of statement, and so easily got it in large number. We don't *have* to use "if, then" to get at this class. "The model predicts" also seems to get at this class, if/then phrasing just helps frames things better (in some cases semantically they mean the same). "The world obeys the lnc" does not get at this class I argue. So I guess I'm asking about non-contingent truths? Is that the term? And why does there seem to be so many of them-I feel like I'm doing something wrong to get this free lunch (more of a feast really).

Essentially, do well-formed "if/then" statements gives us infinitely more non-contingent truths for every contingent one? Is this kind of "dangerous" to some ideas of truth/knowledge?

Comment: This is a good question, and I wish I had time to bring up the general issue of truth-aptitude for conditionals, but for now I'd say: you get a free buffet, but most of the dishes are low-calorie. A lot of "secure" hypotheticals are very generalized or even relatively "trivial" (as mathematicians say) so you're not violating the amount of evidence to accept/use (I hesitate to say "believe," c.f. Wittgenstein on "hinge propositions") these *as* secure; the problem is you might not get much fuel for substantial reasoning from them.

Comment: I don't think you mean "well-formed" because "If water is wet then water is not H2O" has the same form as "if Ken is a bachelor then Ken is not married", but the first is false and the second is a non-contingent truth. Discarding the reference to form, it sounds like you are asking if non-contingent implications are non-contingent, and presumably that's not what you mean to ask.

Comment: What you seem to be expressing are the conditionals used in Mathematical logic courses like if N squared is even, then N+5 is odd.  These do not represent all conditional statements like you noted.  This is one type of conditional statement also know as hypothetical statements.  This type is called NECCESSARY which by definition means if the antecedent is true then the consequent is also true.That is there is no possible way only part of the statement can hold true without the other symbolized as ~(s & ~p).  That is also equivalent to s-->p. For example, If sue is a woman, then Sue is a human.

Comment: "But adding in a finite amount of proper detail would secure these statements or similar against all routing (I claim)". You are mistaken, no finite if-thenization will "secure" anything, see [What the Tortoise Said to Achilles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/What_the_Tortoise_Said_to_Achilles) for Lewis Carroll's funny illustration of why not. And "the world follows/obeys the law of non-contradiction" is a bad example. The world is incapable of obeying or disobeying the LNC, that is non-sensical. LNC only applies to statements about the world, not to the world itself.

Comment: @KristianBerry Thanks for the term "truth-apt". I think I want it make them truth-apt but I don't see them as hypotheticals/conditionals, and maybe that's a part of my problem. If/thens seem like declarative statements...

Comment: @Conifold I'm not sure I buy this treatment. These are all declaratives in my post as I understand them. I'm *not* asking the reader to do anything, accept anything, or answer anything. Im declaring *man* like Aristotle, or pointing to a rock and saying "rock". But that was very helpful thanks, I think it helps show where I need to better understand. Still puzzled though.